# Remove headers and contents from a flat file if they are below a specific line count

Tags: sed, awk

I've a flat file containing about 10 million lines:

```
    query
    ID1
    content1
    content2
    query
    ID2
    content3
    content4
    ...
    content21
    query
    ID3
    content22
    content23
    ...
    content81
```

Any block in the file less than 10 lines should be removed. For example, the first block contains 4 lines (query to content2) and it should be removed. This step need to be done before splitting the blocks into individual files. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done with awk:

```
awk '
# define a long block
BEGIN{
  long = 10;
}
# output long block when new block is found
($1 == "query" && n >= long){
  print s;
}
# new block
($1 == "query"){
  s = "";
  n = 0;
}
# all lines
{
  s = (s != "") ? s "\n" $0 : $0;
  n++;
}
# output the long block if it is the last one in the file
END{
  if (n >= long){
    print s;
  }
}
' input.file > output.file
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -e:q -e'$!N;s/\n/&/9;tS' -e'$!bq'     -e:S    \
         -e's|^query.*\n\(query\)|\1|;tq' -e'/\n/{P;D;}'
```

That will keep 10-lines of the current input file in `sed`'s buffer at all times. For each regular input line `sed` will `P`rint the first of its buffer lines and then `D`elete it. At the top of the `N`ext cycle `sed` will replenish its buffer with the `N`ext input line.

If at any point `query.*\nquery` matches within its 10-line window, `sed` will remove all but the trailing `query` match. And at the top of the next cycle `sed` will gather input until it has replenished all ten lines of its sliding-window buffer before attempting to test input again.

Here is a simple demonstration:

```sh
for i in      3 6 9 12 15 18                                      
do         
      printf "%s %s %s %s%0${i}s" query ID1 content1 content2
done| tr \  \\n| nl -ba -w1 |
sed -e:q -e'$!N;s/\n/&/9;tS' -e'$!bq'   -e:S    \
         -e's|^[0-9]*.query.*\n\([0-9]*.query\)|\1|;tq' \
         -e'/\n/{P;D;}'
```

I modified the regexp slightly to accomodate `nl` for sake of the output:

```
16  query
17  ID1
18  content1
19  content2
20  
21  
22  
23  
24  
25  
26  
27  
28  query
29  ID1
30  content1
31  content2
32  
33  
34  
35  
36  
37  
38  
39  
40  
41  
42  
43  query
44  ID1
45  content1
46  content2
47  
48  
49  
50  
51  
52  
53  
54  
55  
56  
57  
58  
59  
60  
61  query
62  ID1
63  content1
64  content2
65  
66  
67  
68  
69  
70  
71  
72  
73  
74  
75  
76  
77  
78  
79  
80  
81
```

`sed` cuts away all sequences which fully fit within its input-window. It won't miss any, and it doesn't need to buffer any more than the ten lines at a time. If we add a `l`ook to the `sed` script we can see what its buffer looks like:

```
for i in      3 6 9 12 15 18                                      
do         
      printf "%s %s %s %s%0${i}s" query ID1 content1 content2
done| tr \  \\n| nl -ba -w1 |
sed -ne:q -e'$!N;l;s/\n/&/9;tS' -e'$!bq'   -e:S    \
          -e's|^[0-9]*.query.*\n\([0-9]*.query\)|\1|;tq' \
          -e'/\n/{P;D;}'
```

---

```
1\tquery\n2\tID1$
1\tquery\n2\tID1\n3\tcontent1$
1\tquery\n2\tID1\n3\tcontent1\n4\tcontent2$
1\tquery\n2\tID1\n3\tcontent1\n4\tcontent2\n5\t$
1\tquery\n2\tID1\n3\tcontent1\n4\tcontent2\n5\t\n6\t$
1\tquery\n2\tID1\n3\tcontent1\n4\tcontent2\n5\t\n6\t\n7\tquery$
1\tquery\n2\tID1\n3\tcontent1\n4\tcontent2\n5\t\n6\t\n7\tquery\n8\tID\
1$
1\tquery\n2\tID1\n3\tcontent1\n4\tcontent2\n5\t\n6\t\n7\tquery\n8\tID\
1\n9\tcontent1$
1\tquery\n2\tID1\n3\tcontent1\n4\tcontent2\n5\t\n6\t\n7\tquery\n8\tID\
1\n9\tcontent1\n10\tcontent2$
7\tquery\n8\tID1\n9\tcontent1\n10\tcontent2\n11\t$
7\tquery\n8\tID1\n9\tcontent1\n10\tcontent2\n11\t\n12\t$
7\tquery\n8\tID1\n9\tcontent1\n10\tcontent2\n11\t\n12\t\n13\t$
7\tquery\n8\tID1\n9\tcontent1\n10\tcontent2\n11\t\n12\t\n13\t\n14\t$
7\tquery\n8\tID1\n9\tcontent1\n10\tcontent2\n11\t\n12\t\n13\t\n14\t\n\
15\t$
7\tquery\n8\tID1\n9\tcontent1\n10\tcontent2\n11\t\n12\t\n13\t\n14\t\n\
15\t\n16\tquery$
16\tquery\n17\tID1$
16\tquery\n17\tID1\n18\tcontent1$
16\tquery\n17\tID1\n18\tcontent1\n19\tcontent2$
16\tquery\n17\tID1\n18\tcontent1\n19\tcontent2\n20\t$
16\tquery\n17\tID1\n18\tcontent1\n19\tcontent2\n20\t\n21\t$
16\tquery\n17\tID1\n18\tcontent1\n19\tcontent2\n20\t\n21\t\n22\t$
16\tquery\n17\tID1\n18\tcontent1\n19\tcontent2\n20\t\n21\t\n22\t\n23\
\t$
16\tquery\n17\tID1\n18\tcontent1\n19\tcontent2\n20\t\n21\t\n22\t\n23\
\t\n24\t$
```